# How to show all published Application Virtualization (App-V) packages

Tags: app-v

How can I get a list of all the published Microsoft Application Virtualization (App-V) packages? I would like to see both the applications I have access to and also ones that are published but which I do not have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [sftmime command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817090.aspx) to show information about App-V servers, packages, and applications.

To see the list of all published applications, use the [following command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc843749.aspx):

```
sftmime query obj:package /global
```

By default, `sftmime` is located in the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client
```